# Trying to send email with ASP.net, cant pass variables to ashx file

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ashx

First of all, I'm completely new to asp.net, jquery and all the web side stuff.  I don't have a good understanding on any of it.  I've tried to do some research, but I can't figure out my problem.

I bought a template and am now trying to go through this broken code to make it functional.

I have a contact form, the fields look like this:

```
<label class="name">
    <input type="text" value="Name:">
    <span class="error">*This is not a valid name.</span>
        <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
    <span class="clear"></span>
</label>
```

There are 3 or 4 fields that are all the same, except one is a textarea.

Now I think my problem is, I'm not getting the values from the text fields.  Either that or I'm not sending the values correctly.

This is my submit function:

```
submitFu: function () {
    _.validateFu(_.labels)
    if (!_.form.has('.' + _.invalidCl).length)
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: _.mailHandlerURL,
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    'name': +_.getValFromLabel($('.name', _.form)),
                    'email': +_.getValFromLabel($('.email', _.form)),
                    'phone':  _.getValFromLabel($('.phone', _.form)),
                    'message': +_.getValFromLabel($('.message', _.form)),
                    'from': 'email@email.net',
                    'smtpMailServer': + _.smtpMailServer,
                    'stripHTML': 'false'
                    },
                success: function () { _.showFu() },
                error: function (data) { alert(data.responseText); }
})
```

And this is my "getValFromLabel" function, which I REALLY don't understand:

```
getValFromLabel: function (label) {
        var val = $('input,textarea', label).val()
       , defVal = label.data('defVal')
        return label.length ? val == defVal ? 'nope' : val : 'nope'
}
```

I put `alert(+_.getValFromLabel($('.message', _.form)))` on my submit function and it shows "NaN", which makes no sense to me at all.  Thats why I think I'm not getting values correctly.  The contact form returns the error that it doesn't have a from address.

Any ideas???

Comment: Since you're using ASP .NET, you could always just send the email with C# or VB .NET, instead of PHP.

Comment: im using c# in my mail handler file.  I don't believe thats the issue though.  The parameters are never getting that far.  I need to know if I am getting data out of the text fields correctly.

Comment: Or am I not supposed to do a POST when using c#?? How do I call the mail handler file?

Comment: Well, what I'm suggesting is you could use ASP Textbox controls instead of HTML input boxes, and then use C# to extract the information from the page and send it via email.  If you're more comfortable with C# than web languages, that could be much easier.

Comment: gotchya..ill see if I can go about doing that

Comment: I'll post an example as an answer.

Comment: _.getValFromLabel($('.name', _.form)), i think it is function related validateFu, I have not worked on it so cannot tell you the exact problem. can you try changing the validation to http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/, you might get more replies as more number of users use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is basic code using http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

```
<form method="post" class="cmxform" id="form" action="form.php">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Login Form (Enter "foobar" as password)</legend>
        <p>
            <label for="user">Name</label>
            <input id="name" name="name" title="Please enter your name (at least 3 characters)" class="required" minlength="3" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input id="email" name="email" title="Please enter a valid email address" class="required email"/>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="phone">Phone</label>
            <input id="phone" name="phone" title="Please enter a valid phone number" class="required digits" minlength="10" maxlength="15" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="phone">comment</label>
            <textarea id="comment" name="comment" title="Please enter a comment" class="required" rows="10" cols="50" ></textarea>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

here is javascript/jquery code

```
jQuery("#form").validate({
    submitHandler: function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "EMAIL.ashx",//or you can code behind web method/webservice
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                'name': + $("#name").val(),
                'email': + $("#email").val(),
                'phone':  $("#phone").val(),
                'message': + $("#comment").val(),
                'from': 'email@email.net',
                'smtpMailServer': + $("#smtpserver").val(),
                'stripHTML': 'false'
                },
            success: function () { alert("email sent successfully") },
            error: function (data) { alert(data.responseText); }
        })              
    }
});
```

you should point the url to your ashx code since you already have the code/ sample is posted above i am not including it, also passing the smtp details is not recommended, you get the details in you csharp code from web.config

Answer (score 1):

Try using ASP .NET Controls and C# to send the email if you're not extremely comfortable with web languages.

Your markup will look something like:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="SendButton" runat="server" Text="Send" />
```

Obviously, that's just for a single textbox to house a "Name" value, and a button to send the email.  Add several more textboxes as needed.

Then, in the SendButton_Click event, use code like this:

```
string MailBody;
MailMessage myMessage = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient smtpC = new SmtpClient();

myMessage.Subject = "Subject for Email";
myMessage.From = new MailAddress("youremailhere@provider.com", "Your Name");
myMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("destinationemail@provider.com", "Receiver Name");

mailBody = Name.Text; //Get information from webpage

smtpC.send(myMessage); //Send the email via smtp
```

Make sure you put the following references at the top of the C# file:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Mail;
```

Also, to use the SMTP Client, you'll have to add some configuration in your web.config file, like so:

```
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="youremail@gmail.com">
      <network enableSsl="true" userName="youremail@gmail.com"  password="yourpassword" host="smtp.gmail.com"/>
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```